# HDFS check if file is readable

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Is there a way to check if a file on HDFS is readable with the FileSystem api or `LocatedFileStatus` object?

`java.io.File::canRead` can be used for a local filesystem operation, but is there an equivalent for the Java api?

Comment: Yes. First, use [`FileSystem.globStatus(Path, PathFilter)`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathFilter)) to get an array of [`FileStatus`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html). That has [`getPermission()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html#getPermission()).

Comment: Thanks. Does `getPermission()` return the permissions for the particular user calling that API? Ex: if it runs under the Hadoop user Bob `getPermission().getUserAction()` it would return `FsAction.NONE`, but user Mary would get `FsAction.WRITE_EXECUTE`